# Django app on AWS EC2 not returning data for specific computers

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

My Django server does not return data from the AWS RDS database for some users.

I have a Django server deployed to an AWS EC2 instance and setup using Nginx and Uwsgi. I am using an AWS RDS PostgreSQL database to store my data for the same. Every time the front end makes a request to the server, the server reads some data from the database and returns it as a JSON object. 
It works fine for me. However, some users have reported no data being revealed for them on the front-end. So, I tried logging the results of the API call, and I found that for the same request, the request from my computer gets some data, while from some other user's computer - the retrieved data object is empty. (Note: The user has 40Mbps internet speed, so it's not a speed issue per say)

I thought it might be an issue with RDS, so I tried migrating to a different database, but that didn't fix it either. I also tried changing the instance region, but that didn't affect anything either.

Comment: you'll have to give us more details here: do you see the requests in the nginx access logs (show us these logs, one with your request, one with the other users' request), idem for the uwsgi logs and finally show us the django logs. Did you check that django is returning a 200 response and not an error? did you check your django error logs? be more specific in what you've tried to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. So I was getting the Date from the user's computer in the API call and using that to query the database. Apparently, due to a difference in date formats for users, mm/dd/yyyy users were getting no data because no data existed for that format.